# ETA on new User Activity page for non-Meta.SE sites?

Tags: discussion

The [new User Activity page](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/249951/help-us-test-the-shiny-new-user-activity-page-plus-a-bunch-of-new-features) looks great, but there's no ETA specified as of now. Perhaps some moderator can leak some informations about ETA for non-Meta.SE sites?

Comment: It'll be ready in [6-8 weeks.](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/19514)

Comment: @jrg - post that as an answer ?

Comment: @jrg Yes, post an answer about that. I can't wait!!!

Comment: @jrg Nope ok you trolled me. Wow you got me over there! I wish I could undo my upvote on your comment!

Comment: @kos sorry, i originally posted it as a answer with more stuff about how we don't know, but the site auto converted it to a comment and trimmed it. :-(

Comment: The real answer is "No clue." Timeframes are a vague, unfamiliar, and dangerous thing. It might be tomorrow, it might be next year. We don't know.

Comment: @jrg No problem, the concept was delivered in any case. Just joking about the upvote, that was fun since I really fell for that at first. That's what I expected to be told, altough I hoped someone could have narrowed it down to weeks/months/years. Well I'll just wait indefinetly then!

Comment: **NOW!** Complaints and kudos are being found at http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/13782/minor-site-design-updates?cb=1

Comment: It went live today!

Comment: @Seth Exactly within the last 10 minutes I think, very nice!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

SOON(tm)

We're getting very close to release the new user profile on our top sites. Ask Ubuntu community is one of them! In fact, I'm making some minor site design updates to the site in preparation for the new user profile.

Comment: Nice, I like these changes already, expecially the StackOverflow-style badges. Can't wait for the full upgrade!

Comment: `ERROR: Developer.class("stackoverflow") returned timeframe "SOON", expected "6 to 8 weeks"` ;-)

Comment: @jrg `[Kernel Panic] process StackOverflow returned type 'timeframe' for expected type 'nonspecific statement'  at memory address 0xDEADBEEF, and has died, killing init in the process.`