# Minor site design updates

Tags: discussion, design

As you can see, Ask Ubuntu community site got a slight design update today. I have moved site's CSS to a newly refactor LESS system, so it's more maintainable for us to fix SE network CSS bugs globally going on forward. I've standardized some common site elements and UI conventions. For example, only accepted answers on the home page and question list page get a more prominent treatment. I have removed the Ubuntu orange color for unanswered background color. (The orange was a bit over used before). I try to keep the overall look and feel the same as before. The new changes will make it easier for us launch new [site features](http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/13776/eta-on-new-user-activity-page-for-non-meta-se-sites) as well.

**Site's logo and icons are now in SVG for retina support!**

This update should retro-actively fix most of the old CSS bugs. If you see any new ones, or old ones not being fixed, please let me know!

Comment: Thanks for the update!

Comment: I have the feeling code looks much nicer now :)

Comment: @JacobVlijm let's just say we trimmed this site's own .css file by 3k+ lines... past me was a noob.

Comment: I would love to have the orange circle on questions with no answers back. In my opinion it was good to highlight them. If you don't like orange, you could also think of another way, of course...

Comment: The favorite tags grey background is lost (UPDATE: almost invisible) on questions and editing the favorites put the Add button out of the div (only 10% of it is visible)

Comment: The badges seem now less prominent - is that on purpose? Maybe I'll need to arrange an appointment with my optician  or look for the magnifying glass to appreciate other's efforts....

Comment: Looks a lot better :)

Comment: Looks good, some (minor) color issues, some things show blue rather then orange. I am sure as the theme is used these can be resolved and the theme will be more consistent. Example, in "featured" the little box is highlighted in blue.

Comment: @Jin you've got me wanting to smack things with the printed bash manpage (>300 pages) now with these changes.  Blue != orange.  Font size is now *smaller* than it was on the main page, and is annoying on wide-screens or high-res screens.  The grey used in place of black is less readable on the main page *and* in the editing windows for editing answers/questions.  Font size overall has been reduced, making it harder to read anything, comments included. And what font did you put on here, it's not playing nice on my 14.04 system.  What prompted these changes???

Comment: I agree about the inconsistencies of the box colors and about the text being slightly too thin, but I also understand that this is a work in progress, I don't really know the details of how everything has been scheduled, so I won't judge, perhaps this is intended for other reasons (e.g. the upcoming User Activity page). I personally like almost every change by the way. +1

Comment: So much hate :-(

Comment: @kos if this is a "Work in Progress" then it needs to be set up in a staging environment, not in production.  Another -1 for incompetency as a result of not using a staging environment as a preview, and just blindly applying to production.  BAD DEV CYCLE WORK, JIN!

Comment: Meta design functions are bad too.  What was previously orange for mod-only tags are now pink.  -1 again.

Comment: @ThomasW. that's how it is everywhere else on the network. I can understand that they want a more uniform look across SE. For one thing, it would make fixing things much easier.

Comment: @ThomasW.  Still, perhaps they need to test it on a larger scale, or they have another reason, I'm not an expert. Or perhaps you are right, and something could have been done better. I honestly have no clue. Anyway what I'm positive about is that the more users involved in testing, the better the result will be, this way everyone can spot issues/democratically express opinions/contribute to make it better, so this at some point should have happened anyway. After all this is how new features had always been introduced on Stack Exchange sites

Comment: Anyway looks like the font has been adjusted a bit,and now it's much better. Instead, the blue in the boxes now started actively hurting my eyes! :) That's my only complain for now anyway, almost all really looks fine

Comment: @Seth re: so much hate - you get these sort of comments whenever you change themes. I have been active on several large sites and you NEVER get 100 % community agreement for such changes. Take it as free feedback, some people pay consultants for such feedback.

Comment: @bodhi.zazen It wasn't the disagreement that I was sad about, that always happens. It was the strong and, IMO, inappropriate ways that people have expressed their disagreement that makes me sad.

Comment: @Seth Oh believe me, I know how you feel. I have always found it odd and irritating the tone some users use in giving feedback, sometimes from long term users.

Comment: I just noticed. The updates. Then this post.

Comment: The bold text in questions and answer also sticks out a little to much for my taste. Perhaps it's just too black. Something a little closer to the question title's color would be nicer.

Comment: @Jin the upvote button on comments looks very weedy compared to what it was. Could it be made a little thicker again? With url("img/sprites.svg?v=500bea8c7173") rather than the current one?

Comment: I don't agree with what people have been saying - you don't deserve this anger, but it would be nice to see some changed back. I get that a lot of this take a **lot** of time, but it is still going to annoy me each time I visit :/

Comment: A per [Is AskUbuntu boring?](http://meta.askubuntu.com/q/12149/178596), the badges and stuff I think are supposed to be similar to canonical certification icons or something. Thanks for putting the effort in to redesigning stuff, it seems to result in a cleaner UI (albeit with the odd annoying bit :)

Comment: I find it funny that you call these "minor" site design updates...  They're overall good and make this site mos consistent with other sites, but **please**: *never do any "major" site re-design!*  The most you should aim for from now on, is *a few tiny ones!*  **:D :D :D**

Comment: Why You added blue color? In my opinion I does not look good with overall orange design. 'Bounty information' with orange background looked way better.

Comment: Super cool now. This "minor", almost imperceivable change which I did not  even noticed looks SUPER AWESOME!.

Comment: I hated it at first, love it now.

Answer (score 14):

[status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

I can no longer see which questions are tagged with my favorite tags:

[image: example showing a highlighted question]

The middle of the three questions shown above is highlighted because it is tagged with one of my favorite tags. Assuming this is not a question of my screen being miscalibrated, I'm sure you agree that the highlight is almost invisible.

The normal background is pure white (`#ffffff`) and the highlight is `#fafafa` which is really too similar. Please make this more visible.

Comment: I'm going to put a fix for this today.  The old favorite tag was too dark, but I think I went overboard lightening it. How do you feel about the light yellow I use on Stack Overflow for favorite tag background color?

Comment: @Jin thanks. I think that the yellow would look out of place here. I suspect that a light orange might fit with the rest of the site better, but you're the designer. If you think it'll look OK with the rest of the site, give it a shot.

Comment: The fix is now live. Dunno if we should delete this, edit it or do nothing.

Comment: @Seth see update. That's what I've been seeing on other sites as a way of marking bugs as fixed.

Answer (score 11):

[status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

I'm not sure if this is new or not, but I find the green used in the front page to show the number of answers a question hard to read:

[image]

Do I need new glasses or is the word *answer* blurry? Perhaps there's not enough contrast between the foreground green and the background? Or is it an anti-aliasing issue? Either way, could it be fixed please?

Answer (score 8):

Posting a screenshot as an "anwser" as an example of the blue hightlight. I would consider changing the color to match the rest of the site.

Feel free to delete this "answer" after you have considered the colors

[image]

Comment: I kinda like the blue highlighting myself :p

Comment: to each their own, it just seem out of place with the rest of the palatte

Comment: I think the pink mod tags are worse... Just my humble opinion.

Comment: Ok, after a little while the blue is starting to bother me. It makes things a bit too bright. Maybe they should be orange after all :P

Comment: How I'd like the squares to be: [imgur](http://i.imgur.com/NFHyX4D.png) (#DE4508, matching the navigation bar)

Comment: But having seen the new (yellow) labels for the pending flags, I have to say I'd fancy something close to that color either! Or even better something in between the two.

Comment: I created a [userscript](https://gist.github.com/Seth-Johnson/2127cebe0c4c6e5277de) to change it back to orange.

Answer (score 8):

The "**other (needs a moderator attention)**" flag textbox overflows the "I'm flagging this question because" window

[Link to full image on Imgur.com](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kTQ6g.png)

[image: Image-1]

Comment: Yes, I've noticed this too. I'm using Firefox 37 (37.0+build2-0ubuntu1), in case that's relevant to troubleshooting this bug.

Comment: Google Chrome 41.0.2272.118 (64-bit) here

Comment: The issue still exists in the revamped flag dialog.

Comment: Same here on Firefox 37

Answer (score 7):

## Complaints.

---

Mod-only flags on meta are now red, instead of orange with white text like it was.  Aesthetically it clashes.

[image: Snippet]

---

Multiple complaints here...

- Font size was reduced, makes it a lot harder to read on high-res screens.  This font size reduction is only on the pages here - the actual 'Question size' on the font doesn't change one layer down on the actual questions.
- No green circle around "2 answers".  Affects aesthetics, less so than readability, but it looks garish as is now.
- No orange border around the "No Answers" items like we had.  (Affects readability and aesthetics)

[image]

---

Uniformity needs to give way to aesthetics.  While most of my complaints here are aesthetic in nature, you can have 'uniformity' but also include aesthetics with respect to the site theme/design.

Comment: Good points all....

Comment: Thomas: You should refrain from writing these things when you've had too little sleep: they make you sound like the old cranky fart that I am!  **;-)**

Answer (score 6):

The number of answers circle seems slightly oval (38x40px), and the number is slightly off centre.

> [image]

> [image]

Comment: The CSS technique used is to round off the borders off a box shaped element so it becomes round, and setting the height of the box to 34px seems to fix this but break other bits - some of the CSS classes are relevant: `.stats .answered strong, .stats .unanswered strong, .stats .answered-accepted strong, .answered-accepted .mini-counts, .answered .mini-counts, .unanswered .mini-counts`. I'm not that bothered about the oval but the centring thing is a bit weird. it works anyways.

Answer (score 6):

New profile page weirdness:

Underline from hovering over tab headers looks weird with the blue box over the number of unread items:

[image]

This is also inconsistent with the overall tab headings, which don't have any underline:

[image]

Underline from hovering over the reputation graph looks just plain weird:

[image]

Comment: +1 but what do you think, would it be better to condensate all the issues about the UI here or to ask a new question about the new user profile and user activity pages specific issues?

Comment: @kos I don't know. Will there be that many issues with the new profile page? Let's see if Jin responds.

Answer (score 5):

**Make the two green colours in the Rep sections same**

[image]

I feel that the two different shades of green used here **do not look aesthetically pretty**.(Well, at least in my honest, personal opinion)

---

**Accept tickmark is not properly centered**

To me, the tickmark under accepted answer votes, does not look to be properly centered within the circle.
[image]
Maybe the tickmark should be just a little bit towards left.

Comment: I think the angle of the checkmark is pretty much centered.

Comment: 1: I like it that way, it draws the attenction on the latest reputation changes instead that on the summary. 2: As Jacob Vlijm said the mark's angle it's centered on the circle's vertical axis, but I feel like everything would look nicer if the mark's vertical axis was centered on it instead

Comment: I agree that the checkmark is not centered properly. Although the bottom of the checkmark is horizontally centered, I feel like the *smallest circle containing the checkmark* should be centered within the larger circle instead.

Comment: Part of these [image sprites](http://cdn.sstatic.net/askubuntu/img/sprites.svg?v=d1bab82d7e68), probably be easy to fix.

Answer (score 4):

The background colour used for the flags in the flag queue is gone which makes the flags hard to read. Could you darken that a bit more, closer to what it used to be?

[image]

Another issue I've run into is the contrast between the orange squares and the number they hold makes it really hard to read (this one is quite hard to show in a screenshot, but hopefully it gets the idea across).

[image]

I'm personally fond of the colour used but I'm afraid something is going to have to be changed to keep those more readable.

Thanks for all the awesome work you do around here Jin!

Answer (score 2):

1. The font size of the body text in the questions and answers looks larger than it was before on my computer.
2. The line spacing of the body text looks smaller than it was before.

The combination of these two factors makes the text look too squeezed together. Either increasing the line spacing, decreasing the font size or both together would improve the readability.

Answer (score 2):

The comment upvotes button is much thinner:

New:

[image]

Old:

[image]

Please go back to chunkier upvotes.

My pronouns are He / Him

Answer (score 2):

In short:

I really can't help the fact that I like the overall changes.

- The less "square" looking font, especially, the
- Prettier looks of python :) code
- The less "obsessive" use of orange, bigger variety in use of color(s)

I noticed a few minor changes/improvements were made since this post appeared.

Really, really nice.

Answer (score 2):

**edit reviews: the suggestion comment is not highlighted any more**

The comment from the suggesting person used to be immediately visible (different background IIRC)

Now it doesn't look differently than the rest[image]

Answer (score 1):

### Bring back some emphasis for questions with 0 answer please

I used to try and do my bit by **giving priority to those questions which have no answer at all**, and I could see them very very easily when they had that **orange circle**.

Now it's very hard to easily spot them, and I don't think the argument "*too much orange color used in the website*" can justify lack of a stronger emphasis for **0 answer questions**.

For example, only the number 0 (without a circle) could be made **red**, or a **light grey circle** could be used, etc. This problem, I think, will have an **adverse effect on the overall number of answers** as it puts off people like me.
[image]

Comment: It seems we should be posting new questions now. http://meta.askubuntu.com/a/13925/158442

Answer (score 0):

Daily reputation seems inaccurate. I just noticed this:

[image: rep]

reputation shows -1 in blue, but achievements shows +10 I'm not certain this is related to the design update, but I couldn't find any related questions so I thought it might be.

Comment: The design update shouldn't have been able to affect any of the logic going on behind the scenes. I'm guessing caching is at work here too. You might have just needed to reload the page as well.

Comment: The `-1` in blue in the "reputation" tab only shows the reputation change since you last clicked on the tab itself, while the `+10` in green in the recent achievements shows always the total day reputation

Answer (score -2):

We are using pretty quotes in titles here and in Unix & Linux, where it's been [pointed out](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3432/70524) for some time. I get that you wish to clean up code and make things prettier, but please "fix" that which is broken.

Comment: You have a legitimate complaint here but why are you being so aggressive about it? "-1 for incompetence?" Seriously? Do you have any idea how complex setting up styles for so many different sites is? The SE devs have already stated that they are looking into it and it's been [less than 3 weeks](http://meta.unix.stackexchange.com/questions/3429/site-design-updates/3432#comment5233_3432).  Please be nice and remember that pissing off the people who are making this for you is not the best way of getting it done.

Comment: @terdon do you know what a 'staging' environment is?  They need one next time, rather than changing the production environment.

Comment: @ThomasW. we have a test environment and test themes before they go live. This was consciously *not* changed. We looked at the last several hundred posts and almost all of them are correctly quoted with fancy quotes. Changing the quoting behavior would be a net-negative we don't want to do.

Comment: @NickCraver this is admittedly a problem for the technical sites. Especially *nix-related ones where quoting is an Issue®. Any chance of changing that at least for AU and U&L? Consider that it breaks copy/pasting since the fancy quotes are not recognized by the shell.

Comment: @NickCraver as terdon said, fancy quotes use a form of quotes which will explode in a shell / terminal environment - that means that you break the functionality of code pastes which would then  be copy-pasted into terminals.  As was said, it's an Issue that would detract overall from the site and break a lot of things for people using copy-paste to put code in the terminal to execute.

Comment: If you actually expect folks to copy code out of question titles, I'm afraid there are much, much bigger / nastier usability issues we'd have to contend with first, @ThomasW (depending on your browser and platform, this is currently either trivial but poorly documented or frustrating and exceedingly error-prone even in the absence of any character replacements).

Comment: @terdon yes, seriously. How else am I supposed to voice my dismay, if I can't use even a meaningless down vote (we are not on [meta.se], remember, where votes do count for something)? And I don't care about offending anyone because I don't expect to see this bug fixed anyway.

Comment: @muru it's the _incompetence_ I find excessive, not the fictitious downvote.  I'm just saying it's a shame because you raise  a valid point but because of the way you stated it, it's getting downvoted. Perhaps you could delete this and post it again as a request instead of an admonishment?

Comment: @NickCraver I don't expect users to do that, however experience has taught me that users are not inherently bright enough to NOT do such things.

Comment: @terdon aargh. This is why I must always include `:P`.

Comment: @terdon I have cleaned up this post - I'm leaving it as it is, since SE employees have already commented here that this is WONTFIX.