# Underline on new reputation graph looks weird

Tags: bug, design, profile-page, reputation-graph

This is what I see when hovering my reputation graph in the new profile page:

> [image]

Can the underline please be removed?

Comment: Related: http://meta.askubuntu.com/a/13850/158442

Comment: Yeah, saw that, but since the new design is kind of permanent now, better start a full fledged report. :)