# How shall we report bugs in the new design?

Tags: support

Are the "answers" to [Minor site design updates](https://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/13782/minor-site-design-updates?cb=1) still monitored or should we post standard bug reports (aka "questions")?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just post standard bug reports at this point. Make sure you tag them [bug](/questions/tagged/bug) and [design](/questions/tagged/design).

Thanks for reporting these :)