# Questions with 0 answers not highlighted any more :-(

Tags: feature-request, bug, design, unanswered-questions

I used to easily see the questions which have not yet got **any answer** as they were displayed in a **red circle** until recently.

Now it's very hard to easily spot them, and I don't think the argument "*too much orange color used in the website*" can justify lack of a stronger emphasis for **0 answer questions**. This problem, I think, will have an **adverse effect on the overall number of answers** as it puts off people who prefer focusing on unanswered questions.

I think it was a useful feature to **draw attention to unanswered questions** more than others already answered (accepted or not).

Perhaps it might be a good idea to bring that feature back.

For example, only the number 0 (without a circle) could be made **red**, or a **light grey circle** could be used, etc.

[image]

Comment: See http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/13924/how-shall-we-report-bugs-in-the-new-design on how to act on this ;)

Comment: btw -  it was an orange circle ...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I agree with this since I mainly focus on questions with 0 answers myself.

It was a useability decision and probably happenend with this announcement: http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/13782/minor-site-design-updates

We do still have this option: https://askubuntu.com/unanswered