# edit reviews: the suggestion comment is not highlighted any more

Tags: bug, design

The comment from the suggesting person used to be immediately visible (different background IIRC)

Now it doesn't stand out from the rest, making it *a bit* harder to find the comment and compare it to the actually suggested edit.

[image: screenshot]

Comment: It's [the same with the flag queue too.](http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/13782/minor-site-design-updates/13790#13790)