# User profile tabs are double-underlined on hover

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, profile-page

When one hovers over a tab name on user profile / activity page, the name gets underlined twice, in addition to changing color to red. I suspect this may be a CSS bug, because having three effects on hover (color change, highlight on the line below, and underline directly under the word) seems too many.

[image: tabs]

Seen in Chrome 47 and Firefox 43. For a live demonstration, see the profile of [this valuable contributor](https://askubuntu.com/users/current?tab=topactivity).

(kos pointed out [this report](http://meta.askubuntu.com/a/13850), which is related but focuses on the bounty indicator. There has been no response to that one.)

Comment: This also happen on [unix.se].

Comment: I noticed, that this does not happen on meta profile, but does happen on the main site and it is the same for many users, as well as U&L and U&L meta, strange.

Comment: @Seth fixing there, too

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This has been fixed in the source, and will be available after the next deploy. Thanks.